# Gulp does not work minify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Iam starter with Gulp. I installed Gulp and using command `npm install --save-dev gulp-uglify` installed this to `C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/gulp/node_modules` folder `gulp-uglify`.

To gulp file I wrote:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
   uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default', function(){
gulp.src('/js/*.js')
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('minijs'));
});
```

Now when I placed to `C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/gulp` folder `js` with some JS file and at command line at `C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/gulp` write `gulp` I find any new folder (as *minijs*).

Can I ask where I must place folder `js`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That´s because you've set the path as `/js/*.js`. This will match the files at the root, not the current folder.

So change it to `./js/*.js` or simply remove the slash.

Also, it's not really recommanded to do this in your *node_modules* folder.